# How to create a hosts file shortcut with administrator privileges?

Tags: windows-7

As a developer, I find myself editing the `hosts` file quite often to add a local virtual host.

As the `hosts` file needs to be edited as an administrator, I have to:

1. Click on the start menu
2. Type `notepad`
3. Right-click on the notepad icon, click *Run as administrator*
4. Click *Yes*
5. Then *Open...* `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Quite cumbersome.

I've tried to create a shortcut to the `hosts` file on the desktop, then right-click it to change the shortcut *advanced* properties, but I can't select *Run as administrator*.

[image: Shortcut advanced properties]

I guess this is because I'm creating a shortcut to a file, and not to the `notepad` program.

**How can I create a shortcut to notepad that runs as an administrator and opens the hosts file?** It's OK if I have to click *Yes* every time to confirm that I want to run the program as an administrator.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here you go:

> 

1. Right click on the desktop
2. New > Shortcut
3. type "notepad" as the location
4. Give the shortcut a name
5. Right click -> Properties on the shortcut
6. to the end of the "target" text box, append "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" (remember to leave a space)
7. Click on "Advanced"
8. Check Run as Administrator
9. then press OK, on both windows

There you are, you will need to confirm with UAC each time you use this.

Comment: Works, thanks! Missing a backslash after `%SYSTEMROOT%` though, and I can't edit your post without editing at least 6 chars.

Comment: @Benjamin got it on my end!, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Works with VSCode with target: `"C:\Program Files\VSCode\Code.exe" %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: +1 for niceness!

Comment: I hate how cumbersome windows makes this, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

- **CMD batch without UAC confirmation**

  Open a new text file, copy&paste the line and save it as `something.cmd`

  ```
  runas /profile /user:Administrator /savecred "notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
  ```
- **Shortcut without UAC confirmation**

  Right-click on desktop » New » Shortcut

  ```
  cmd /c runas /profile /user:Administrator /savecred "notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
  ```

---

Both methods will ask for the administrator password first time and save it.
This only works if your administrator account is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Elegant solution, but: 1/ I don't understand what you mean with *Open a new text file*, did you mean *New shortcut*? 2/ I don't use the Administrator account unfortunately, and indeed this doesn't work with my user account (even though I have the privileges to run as administrator).

Comment: Edited my answer for clarification

Comment: Thanks! Best solution *if you have the Administrator account enabled*.

Answer (score 3):

Create a folder with full permissions for everyone and add it to PATH.

Inside it create a file called `sudo.cmd` with following text inside:

```
@echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") > %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo args = Right("%*", (Len("%*") - Len("%1"))) >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo objShell.ShellExecute "%1", args, "", "runas" >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@cscript %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
```

Now, typing `sudo notepad` will start Notepad with Administrator privileges (with UAC prompt first). It's really handy (you can also `sudo cmd` or `sudo AnyAppYouCanThinkOf`).

Then create a file called `hosts.cmd` and save it with following line:

```
@sudo notepad %systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Now just press <kbd>Win</kbd> and type `hosts`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you have an UAC prompt to open the *hosts* file in Notepad!